# Image Textures don't apply properly

Tags: texturing, uv, image, uv-image-editor

So I've UV unwrapped my mesh and created and baked the texture I desired. But when I go into another Blender project to test my new textures, one of my meshes(This is separate mesh and is not a part of the main mesh) has a really messed up  ... UV (I think)? Reference pics below on what I mean.

The first picture is from the build file and the second is from the texture test file. [image]

[image]

Comment: How many UV maps does object have? Probably you exported object with a wrong map which doesn't correspond to the bake you did. Open UV maps rollout in the Properties editor of the source file and check how many UV maps are there and which one is required for baked image

Comment: I think you could explain a bit better what is the issue. So have you built the object in one .blend file and then appended it to another .blend file? That really shouldn't mess up anything surely.

Comment: @ManuJärvinen correct. Yea sorry, I'm a bit of a mess right now trying to get this worked out for a project.

Comment: @MrZak The entire head is all connected to 1 UV map and I exported the correct one.